# How to convert eloquent statement to sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, eloquent

Is there any way to convert laravel eloquent to sql query?? I hope it's like a web generator or script or something where we just paste the eloquent and the result is an sql query.

I know we can use ->toSql() in laravel but sometimes I need it directly in the database manager to test it, whereas eloquent can't be executed in Database Manager of course because it is one of Laravel's features.

Comment: `->toSql()` is the closest, since it uses PDO with parameter binding. The only other way is to turn on the general log in the database, run the query, and check the sql logs to find the exact query.

Comment: u can also use [debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to see the quieries u r doing in the current request

Comment: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar here is the link of laravel debugbar this is the git repository of source code where you can access that

Comment: where as the other tool i.e online you can use is laravel to sql converter

Comment: thank you for responding to my question. but it all still must first run the program. What I'm hoping for is that I just copy the Eloquent code from my script and paste it into the tool or whatever so that where there is a Convert button it will generate a query. Of course in the eloquent there is a Model name that is not a table name, but this is easy to change to the actual table name.

Answer (score 2):

`toSql()` method returns query and the parameters separately. You can see the exact query that runs in database using this snippet.

```
function toSql($eloquent_query){
  return vsprintf(
    str_replace('?', '%s', str_replace('%', '%%', $eloquent_query->toSql())
  ), collect($eloquent_query->getBindings())->map(function ($binding) {
      return is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'{$binding}'";
  })->toArray());
}
```

Or you can create macro in `AppServiceProvider`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
...
Builder::macro('toCompiledSql', function () {
  return vsprintf(
    str_replace('?', '%s', str_replace('%', '%%', $this->toSql())
  ), collect($this->getBindings())->map(function ($binding) {
      return is_numeric($binding) ? $binding : "'{$binding}'";
  })->toArray());
});

// use it as
User::query()->where('email', 'test@mail.com')->toCompiledSql();
```